# How to add and remove rows with buttons using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How I can add rows while clicking on the `+` button. And delete rows while clicking on the `-` button
Below is the code.

please assist me with guidelines or even a piece of code in `javascript` that I can use to add and delete rows using the `buttons`.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <form method="POST">
           <div class="form-row">
              <div class="col">
                    Dish Name<input type="text" class="form-control" id="dish_name">
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                    Price<input type="text" class="form-control" id="price">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    Description<input type="text" class="form-control" id="description">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-row" id="container">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    Name<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    Unit<input type="text" class="form-control" id="description">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    Price<input type="text" class="form-control" id="price1">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" id="add-row"><span>+</span></button>
                    
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="form-row" id="container1">
            </div>      
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var data = '<div class="col-md-3">'
                    + 'Name<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">'
                    + '</div>'

                    + '<div class="col-md-3">'
                    + 'Unit<input type="text" class="form-control" id="description">'
                    + '</div>'

                    + '<div class="col-md-3">'
                    + 'Price<input type="text" class="form-control" id="price1">'
                    + '</div>'

                    + '<div class="col-md-3">'
                    + '<button type="button" id="delete-row"><span>-</span></button>'
                    
                    + '</div>'
                    + '</div>'
            $('#add-row').click(function(){
                $('#container1').append(data);
            });
        });

      </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First wrap your data html , by a container with specific class , example `<div class="input-wrapper row"> ...</div>` then you should replace the delete btn `id` by `class` attribute , (semantic error for duplicate id) ,

also in order to not break the layout , replace the `container1` class `from-row` by `form-group`

```
<div class="form-group" id="container1">
   ...
</div>
```

at the end just add event delegation on the delete-row" button to delete wrapped div input as :

```
$('#container1').on("click", ".delete-row", function() {
    $(this).parents(".input-wrapper").remove();
});
```

see below working snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = '<div class="input-wrapper row"><div class="col-md-3">' +
    'Name<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">' +
    '</div>'

    +
    '<div class="col-md-3">' +
    'Unit<input type="text" class="form-control" id="description">' +
    '</div>'

    +
    '<div class="col-md-3">' +
    'Price<input type="text" class="form-control" id="price1">' +
    '</div>'

    +
    '<div class="col-md-3">' +
    '<button type="button" class="delete-row"><span>-</span></button>'

    +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>'
  $('#add-row').click(function() {
    $('#container1').append(data);
  });
  
  $('#container1').on("click", ".delete-row", function() {
    $(this).parents(".input-wrapper").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <form method="POST">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
        Dish Name<input type="text" class="form-control" id="dish_name">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        Price<input type="text" class="form-control" id="price">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
        Description<input type="text" class="form-control" id="description">
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-row" id="container">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Name<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        Unit<input type="text" class="form-control" id="description">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        Price<input type="text" class="form-control" id="price1">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="button" id="add-row"><span>+</span></button>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="container1">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The wrapper will break the responsive column layout. Probably better to just add a new class to existing markup

Comment: @charlietfl , you're right , the form-row already represent a `row` div , thus the break (-15 padding) , so replacing by `form-group` and adding a `row` div will fix the issue ,

Comment: How I can display data in a tabular form using jquery ajax like dish_name, price, and multiple dish ingredients(name, unit, price)?

Comment: @AkashChevli , welcome , first if the above answer helpd you accept it , and for your new need you have to ask other question , because it's not related to this question